# How can I handle an empty list when saving to/loading from a string?

Tags: java

I am saving and loading lists of strings to a database.

To save, I do: `list.toString()`

And to load, I use: `Arrays.asList(string.split("\\s*,\\s*"))`

However, when I save an empty list, it gets loaded into a list with one element, the empty string `""`.

What is the best way to avoid this?

Comment: if(empty) return null; ?

Comment: @Vash-DamianLeszczyński what if I really do have a list with the element `""`? I need a way to correctly return a list with an empty string if I started with a list with an empty string, and return a list with no elements if I started with a list with no elements.

Comment: @Unihedron If I have an list with `[""]` , I want a way to save it to a string and load `[""]` from it. If I have `[]`, I currently get `[""]`, not the correct `[]`.

Comment: That was not the final answer, a hint. You have to implement the logic for such case. You can distinct on DB level an empty String and a null value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bad idea anyway, think about the case where a string contains quotes or commas.

You should use a proper serialization utility that will escape them out. CSV, JSON or XML parsers will all do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

In your saving mechanism:

```
if(list.isEmpty()){
    return null;
}
```

And loading:

```
if (string == null)
    return empty list;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem happens at the stage when you save your list: a list with a single empty string produces the same output as the `toString()` call on an empty list (i.e. a `""`).

However, the root problem is that you are not saving a list in a database structure suitable for storing lists - namely, a separate table related to the parent table by a foreign key. This would be the first approach that I would explore - adding a separate table, and storing list elements there. This would make the problem of parsing irrelevant.

If you insist on storing a list as a single value, you need to work out a scheme that would produce different strings for these two conditions. For example, you could write your own `toString` method that appends a comma after the last element, and chop off the last element of the result of `String.split`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to stop saving lists in database as a coma separated strings. This is not a common way to deal with lists when working with DB. If it is relational database create table with foreign key to the base table and store each element of list in its record. When reading use join.

If you are working with noSQL DB check what your DB provides for lists. For example Cassandra supports list type with CQL.

But as a temporary work around use `if` statement to work with empty strings. Decide what do you want to create: empty list or `null` and do something like:

```
List<String> list = "".equals(str) ? Collections.emptyList() : str.split("\\s*,\\s*");
```